# Как приостановить привязку данных?

Tags: c#, checkbox, bindingsource

Есть `CheckBox` с привязанным `CheckState`. В рантайме меняется источник данных у `BindingSource`(к которому привязан `CheckBox`). В это время вылетает исключение о невозможности привязки к столбцу. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ приостановить привязку? Или только удалять привязку и заново добавлять ее?

> Привязка к свойству или столбцу `ID_SOURCE` для `DataSource`
>   невозможна. Имя параметра: `dataMember`

```
в System.Windows.Forms.BindToObject.CheckBinding()
   в System.Windows.Forms.Binding.CheckBinding()
   в System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnMetaDataChanged(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   в System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetBindings(Boolean metadataChanged)
   в System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.SetList(IList list, Boolean metaDataChanged, Boolean applySortAndFilter)
   в System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
   в GUI.Forms.AdsForm.AdsEditHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) в d:\Projects\TEST\GUI\Forms\AdsForm.cs:строка 435
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в GUI.Program.Main() в d:\Projects\TEST\GUI\Program.cs:строка 121
   в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: А что за исключение? Дайте стектрейс.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тексту исключения, в новом источнике данных нет колонки/поля с названием `ID_SOURCE`. Нужно удалять старую привязку, менять источник данных, затем добавлять новую привязку.

Comment: На самом деле он там есть, только нужно установить `DataMember` у `BindingSource`. Только он не дает это сделать. Либо сразу ругается на то, что нет колонки, либо если делать в обратном порядку - что нет такого `DataMember` в данном источнике